# What is the incentive to picking Vladimir over Mordekaiser?

Tags: league-of-legends

*I'm talking about top lane. But the comparison could apply to any other lane as well I suppose.*

Why does Vladimir see much more play than Mordekaiser? Is it because of the ultimates alone?

Comment: Can you separate this into a Q&A style question where your answer is in a separate answer below and not in the actual question body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about the ultimates at all. If it were, Morde would get more play because his ultimate is more impactful. It is about general usefulness and safety.

Lets take a look at how these champs compare:

Things shared between **both** champions:

- Health Cost abilities
- Innate tankiness from passives
- Innate lifesteal from an ability ( Ult on Morde, Q on vlad with E amplification )
- Good AOE and Single target damage
- Terrific late game scaling

Lets take a look at what **Mordekaiser** has that **Vladamir** *does not*:

- Ability to turn the game into a 6v4
- Free Armor and Magic Resist with W shield.

It's really not that much, compared to what **Vladimir** has over **Morde**:

- Level 1 sustain
- **Ranged auto attacks**
- **Troll pool escape** that also acts as a soft CC
- AOE Damage Amplification ultimate

I have highlighted the key points why people play Vlad over Morde. With most top laners being melee, ranged champions have an immediate advantage over them in the early game, which can attribute to snowballing through the mid game.
Vladimir also has an escape, something that Mordekaiser lacks. It's not a great escape, but its better than nothing, and can be used to dodge massive amounts of damage at the expense of 20% of your current HP.

In the current state of the game, if a champion doesn't have a form of escape OR hard engage, they aren't typically played.  Mordekaiser has neither.

Comment: I don't really agree with the ranged AA argument, since the majority of Vlad and Mordekaiser's attacks are from ranged abilities. And you can relate mordekaiser's shield to a form of sustain on it's own.

Comment: If you aren't auto attacking, then you aren't playing a ranged top properly.  Although you are right about the shield being a form of sustain, any decent top laner would know how to completely shut down Morde by zoning him out and preventing him from gaining his shield.  He also naturally pushes, opening himself up for ganks (which are easy due to no escapes)

Comment: I'm still not entirely convinced, but I see your point. It does seem somewhat safer to run Vladimir, so i'll do that :)

Comment: At lower ELOs (which I'm guessing you are a bit lower due to asking this question, no offense meant), you are better off running a ranged top anyways, because people don't know how to deal with it. It's why Teemo top is so good at low levels, but much worse at higher

Comment: **Morde would get more play because his ultimate is more impactful.**  This statement couldn't be more false... one of the main reasons people pick vlad is because of his team fighting ult.  The other reason is his splitpushing power.

Comment: @dphil Yes, and no. They are both situational. It doesnt matter how good vlads ult is if your team does no damage because of a fed adc on their team.  Morde ult would make that fed adc on your team for the fight, annihilating the enemy team.  Vlads ult is objectively worse in duels.

Comment: Sure... if you can actually kill the fed adc.  Mord's ult though is pretty easy for a fed adc to sustain through and you won't likely get them to become a ghost on your side for the fight.  In this situation I'd still rather have Vlad's ult.  I will agree though that Vlad's ult isn't near as good in duels though, but 95% of the time is more impactful in a team fight.

Comment: @eyeofthehawks ELO has nothing to do with the question though. It was about the actual differences (strength/weaknesses) of either champion... Not how they were played by the individual.

Comment: @user79760 i know that. It was in response to you not agreeing with the ranged aa argument.

Comment: @eyeofthehawks Upon further thought, I agree with the AA argument actually. So, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I agree w/ @dphil vlad niche pick is only good for split push(he has escapes) and his team fight ult. Morde isnt seen because his ult is too easy to negate as there are too many ways to remove it and the rest of his abilities are kinda meh

Comment: Kill a draven with morde's ult > win the entire teamfight with the ghost > profit.